# Is there a canonical way to identify tangent bundle of $S^{2}$ with the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

The tangent bundle of $S^{2n}$ is given by
$$
TS^{2n}=\{(x, v)\in\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}\times \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}: |x|^2=1, x\cdot v=0\}.
$$
Intuitively we are associating a tangent space to each point on the sphere. When $n=1$, it seems that there should be a way to relate $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)$ with $TS^2$. Moreover, I am wondering is there a canonical way to relate the tangent bundle of $S^{2n}$ with some fiber bundle of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: By $\Bbb P^1$ you mean, of course, $\Bbb CP^1$. Why should $S^{2n}$ have anything to do with $\Bbb CP^n$ when $n>1$? If you think about the Euler characteristic of $S^2$, it will suggest the correct $k$ for $TS^2\cong \mathscr O_{\Bbb P^1}(k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your title question, "no": If we identify the Riemann sphere and the complex projective line, then $TS^{2}$ is identified with the holomorphic line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^{1}}(2)$, e.g., because the constant vector field $\partial/\partial z$ has a double zero at $\infty$ (compare Ted's comment).